# Finding Maximum of an interval in array using binary trees

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree

I'm studying Binary trees! and i have a problem in this Homework.
I have to use binary trees to solve this problem
here is the problem :
You are given a list of integers. You then need to answer a number of questions of the form: "What is the maximum value of the elements of the list content between the A index and the index B?".
example :

```
INPUT :
10
2 4 3 5 7 19 3 8 6 7
4
1 5
3 6
8 10
3 9
OUTPUT:
7
19
8
19
```

TIME LIMITS AND MEMORY (Language: C + +)

Time: 0.5s on a 1GHz machine.
Memory: 16000 KB

CONSTRAINTS

1 <= N <= 100000, where N is the number of elements in the list.

1 <= A, B <= N, where A, B are the limits of a range.

1 <= I <= 10 000, where I is the number of intervals.

Please do not give me the solution just a hint !
Thanks so much !

Comment: Why do you have to use binary trees? If the input gives the index range, why can't you just look at the input list for the given index range and figure out the max number?

Comment: @srikanta : Sorry but i have to use a binary trees this the goal of the exercice !

Comment: How do you construct the binary tree from the given input list?

Comment: every binary tree should have 2^H node in order to create it ! so you have to see if the number of node are equal to 2^h you have to add node until you get 2^(h+1) node.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: @leems : i tried but the solution that i have found was not the best in execution time because i have only 0.5second

Comment: Write out the tree on paper and look at the structure - run through the algorithms you've no doubt been told about. But Look at where the max/min occur in your paper structure... Thats where I'd (and still do) start

Answer (score 2):

As already discussed in the comments, to make things simple, you can add entries to the array to make its size a power of two, so the binary tree has the same depth for all leaves. It doesn't really matter what elements you add to this list, as you won't use these computed values in the actual algorithm.

In the binary tree, you have to compute the maxima in a bottom-up manner. These values then tell you the maximum of the whole range these nodes are representing; this is the major idea of the tree.

What remains is splitting a query into such tree nodes, so they represent the original interval using less nodes than the size of the interval. Figure out "the pattern" of the intervals the tree nodes represent. Then figure out a way to split the input interval into as few nodes as possible. Maybe start with the trivial solution: just split the input in leave nodes, i.e. single elements. Then figure out how you can "combine" multiple elements from the interval using inner nodes from the tree. Find an algorithm doing this for you by *not* using the tree (since this would require a linear time in the number of elements, but the whole idea of the tree is to make it logarithmic).

Answer (score 0):

Write some code which works with an interval of size 0. It will be very simple.

Then write some for a interval of size 1. It will still be simple.

Then write some for an interval of size 2. It may need a comparison. It will still be simple.

Then write some for an interval of size 3. It may involve a choice of which interval of size 2 to compare. This isn't too hard.

Once you've done this, it should be easy to make it work with any interval size.

Answer (score 0):

An array would be the best data structure for this problem.

But given you need to use a binary tree, I would store (index, value) in the binary
tree and key on index.

Comment: An array requires linear time for each query, which is slow. With a binary tree, it can be implemented in logarithmic time for each query. It's even possible in constant time with a different data-structure (still linear-logarithmic space).

Comment: @leemes The problem statement says the lookups are by index and not by value.  Accessing an array by index is as fast as it gets.

Comment: But the query is about finding the maximum value within an index *range* between A and B. And finding the index on an array takes O(B-A) time. The binary tree is not used as a search tree, but for partial reductions.

Comment: @leemes Oh.  I get it now.  The leaves are the values.  The parents are the max of the children.